# Loud Noise, possibly electrical, from somewhere in the house

Tags: electrical

Just today I have heard a loud buzzing noise in the house. I have lived here 16 years and never heard it before. It is loud, lasts a few seconds and sounds electrical. I cannot isolate where it is from. I looked to see if the breaker box had any tripped breakers, no. I also have the furnace running, sounds normal. Does the electrical box make a noise if something is going bad? I shut everything down and turned off the main switch. Then re-started everything. About 20 minutes later, I heard the noise again. It is from somewhere in the basement....Circuit Breaker? Water Heater? Furnace? Any ideas?

Comment: If you can't locate the source of a sound, how do you expect somebody to find it through the internet? If you could record the sound and upload it to YouTube (or similar), somebody might recognize it.

Comment: I tried to identify the sound on the web. Kinda sounds like a fire engine horn. Not the siren, but the horn.

Comment: Like I said. We can't hear the sound, and we can't wander through your home listening for the sound.  Based on the information you've provided, it's impossible for anybody to answer this question accurately.

Comment: Turn off all the breakers, then turn them on one at a time.  Listen for the sound for a bit, before turning on the next breaker.  This might at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: I heard a similar noise when I went to bed (only when I lay down my head on the pillow, it was like electrical vibrations picked up by the bed), for years. It drove me nuts, I couldnt work out what it was but lived with it. Until one day my bed side buld blew and I removed the wall socket transformer (it was a 12vac hologen thing).... Noise stopped. The problem was the bed frame was pressed against the transformer and heard this buzzing. It sounded like my neighbours fan sometimes, even when the light was off.You can try and turn of areas of your house in DB board until the noise stops&find it

Comment: I had this happen recently, turned out to be the doorbell chime, it had somehow jammed and was making a very loud buzzing noise that sounded electrical.